# How to send Whatsapp message to new number

Tags: java, android, whatsapp, android-developer-api

I' d like to send a whatsapp message by clicking on a button to a number that comes from the Android Activity (that in turn fetches from a server). 
The number to which I have to send a new is NOT an existing contact on my phone. 
I know how to open Whatsapp app from my app. 
The following piece of code deals with opening whatsapp from an Adapter:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

this code opens Whatsapp but I don't know how to pass it the number to which I have to send the message

Comment: Check if the answer I posted below meets your need.

Comment: 1. You need add number in your Contact list, 2. Refresh WhatsApp contacts, thats the only work around for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void onClickWhatsApp(View view) {

    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    try {

        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";

        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp",     PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        //Check if package exists or not. If not then code 
        //in catch block will be called
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
   }  

}
```

Comment: Where I add the number ?